# twilio session variable does not return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

I have a simple app where I want to confirm order from my client against a purchase by sms. I am passing a order id with in session variable to my and he will response with y or n to accept or reject order respectively. my code is some thing like this

```
body = "You have a new order of a #{product.title}"
session[:orderId] = @order.id
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
client.account.messages.create(:from => 'myNo', :to => sotre_no, :body => body)
```

and getting response back with

```
from = params["From"]
response = params["Body"]
order = Order.find session[:orderId] #session[:orderId] returns nil why?
if order.confirm(response)
  body = "your order is confirmed! Thanks"
else
  body = "You have reject the order Thanks for your response"
end
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
client.account.messages.create(:from => 'myNo', :to => from, :body => body)
```

I am not able to get order id why any one can help on this or suggest me how can I send order id in params.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio.

Your issue here is that sessions work when a user is browsing your site with a web browser. A cookie identifies the session and is shared with the server each time the browser makes a request.

In this case, you do not have a browser interacting with the site, your user is interacting over SMS. So, there aren't cookies being exchanged and there cannot be a persistent session.

Instead, you will need to save your order in a more permanent store, for example another model. I'm going to call it an `Offer` for now (ie you are offering a product to a user).

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :order

  def self.last_offer_for(phone_number)
    self.include(:user).where(['users.phone_number = ?', phone_number]).first
  end
end
```

Then your initial sending of an SMS would look like this:

```
body = "You have a new order of a #{product.title}"
Offer.create(:order => @order, :user => @user)
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
client.account.messages.create(:from => 'myNo', :to => @user.phone_number, :body => body)
```

and when you receive the message back you would look up the last offer you made to the user by the phone number and get the order from there:

```
from = params["From"]
response = params["Body"]
offer = Offer.last_offer_for(from)
order = offer.order
if order.confirm(response)
  body = "your order is confirmed! Thanks"
else
  body = "You have reject the order Thanks for your response"
end
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
client.account.messages.create(:from => 'myNo', :to => from, :body => body)
```

This is just one option of how to do this, you could save it in a simpler database like a key value store like redis.

I hope this helps, please let me know if I can help any further.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply but my system will behave unexpected in such cases for example a visitor order's for multiple times for a product of same client and off-course client will get sms for each order and if client accepts an order it will always accepts the last order from the customer I hope you got my point.

Comment: I see your point, but sessions are still not going to work in the way you expect. You could, perhaps, require the user to include an id of the order that they are purchasing and detect that in the SMS, but that makes it harder than a yes/no response. The thing is, it's definitely harder to tie together an SMS conversation than it is to retain state during a web based interaction.

Comment: currently I am doing same getting order id back in sms lets go with your solution. But if you have any other solution please let me know Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Session is empty because (I guess) it’s generic handler. You should pass `orderId` to client:

```
client.account.messages.create(
  :from => 'myNo', 
  :to => sotre_no, 
  :body => body,
  :orderId => @order.id # supply orderId
)
```

Now you should be able to retrieve it within

```
order = Order.find params['OrderId']
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but I think we can not pass arguments to twilio api in this way.